# On the existence of a square root for a modular tensor category

Tags: ct.category-theory, fusion-categories, braided-tensor-categories, modular-tensor-categories, unitary-fusion-category

The center $Z(\mathcal{C})$ of a spherical fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) is a modular tensor category.

*Question:* What about the converse, i.e., can we characterize every modular tensor category $\mathcal{M}$ such that the equation $Z(\mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathcal{M}$ admits a solution $\mathcal{C}$ which is a fusion category?

Comment: If you're asking whether or not every UMTC is the double of some UFC the answer is no. Fibonacci is a counter example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A characterization of Drinfeld centers of fusion categories is given in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2117) as braided fusion categories containing a so-called Lagrangian algebra.

Comment: Which is equivalent with $\mathcal C$ being in the the trivial class of the Witt group